# Why does enabling Memory Integrity (HVCI) reduce performance of my Windows 10 QEMU/KVM virtural machine significantly?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm, virtualization-based-security

I have a Windows 10 guest inside of a QEMU/KVM virtual machine that I use for running Windows-only software. Today, I tried enabling "Memory Integrity" inside of it via the Windows Security app by following a guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/device-guard/enable-virtualization-based-protection-of-code-integrity

However, after enabling this and letting the Windows guest reboot, the entire guest system slowed down to a crawl. I was able to disable Memory Integrity again, and after rebooting the performance was back to normal. What gives? I'm on Linux 5.19.13 (provided by Fedora Linux), and QEMU 6.2.0. My CPU is an Intel i5 6200U. Below is my libvirt domain XML:

```
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>76befba5-ca3a-4f33-bdde-8cef7fd94751</uuid>
  <title>Microsoft Windows 10</title>
  <metadata>
    <boxes:gnome-boxes xmlns:boxes="https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes">
      <os-state>installed</os-state>
      <media-id>http://microsoft.com/win/10:9</media-id>
      <media>/home/neboula/Downloads/Win10_21H2_Swedish_x64.iso</media>
    </boxes:gnome-boxes>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
    <edited:edited xmlns:edited="https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes/edited">2022-10-16T22:25:51+0200</edited:edited>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-6.2">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
    <bootmenu enable="no"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv mode="custom">
      <relaxed state="on"/>
      <vapic state="on"/>
      <spinlocks state="on" retries="4096"/>
      <vpindex state="on"/>
      <runtime state="on"/>
      <synic state="on"/>
      <stimer state="on">
        <direct state="on"/>
      </stimer>
      <reset state="on"/>
      <vendor_id state="on" value="KVM Hv"/>
      <frequencies state="on"/>
      <reenlightenment state="on"/>
      <tlbflush state="on"/>
      <ipi state="on"/>
      <evmcs state="on"/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state="on"/>
      <hint-dedicated state="on"/>
      <poll-control state="on"/>
      <pv-ipi state="off"/>
      <dirty-ring state="on" size="4096"/>
    </kvm>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on">
    <feature policy="disable" name="hypervisor"/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="localtime">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" cache="writeback" discard="unmap"/>
      <source file="/home/neboula/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images/win10"/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <target dev="hdc" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="ccid" index="0">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <mac address="52:54:00:04:84:2a"/>
      <source bridge="virbr0"/>
      <target dev="tap0"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <smartcard mode="passthrough" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="ccid" controller="0" slot="0"/>
    </smartcard>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spiceport">
      <source channel="org.spice-space.webdav.0"/>
      <target type="virtio" name="org.spice-space.webdav.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice">
      <listen type="none"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
      <gl enable="no"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich9">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="spice"/>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes">
        <acceleration accel3d="no"/>
      </model>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="6"/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type="dynamic" model="selinux" relabel="yes"/>
</domain>
```

What could I do to get acceptable performance even with Memory Integrity enabled?

Answer (score 0):

**Even without emulation, [Memory Integrity increases security but can decrease performance](https://www.overclock.net/threads/core-isolation-memory-integrity-has-a-major-effect-on-performance.1798410/).**

[Microsoft's info page regarding Memory Integrity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/core-isolation-e30ed737-17d8-42f3-a2a9-87521df09b78) contains a note:

*Memory integrity works by creating an isolated environment using hardware virtualization.*

**Probably QEMU/KVM attempts to emulate hardware components needed for memory integrity.** Both of this together slows things down significantly.